# Awoke or woke up vs came awake

Tags: meaning

> Michael was in deep sleep, then suddenly **came awake**.

So it's the first time I came upon the word "came awake". I assume it means the same as "woke up". Does it really? How it differs from "woke up" or "awoke"? Or is it just not a usual way of saying it? Would you sound normal if you'd use "came awake" on daily basis?

Comment: 'Came awake' uses a very literary style; I'd only expect to see it in very dramatic circumstances such as 'After sleeping for nearly sixty years, the great dragon suddenly sensed a change in the air in the vast cavern, and came awake.' / 'With the economic reforms of Deng Xiao Ping, the sleeping giant came awake in the 1980s'.

Comment: Not really answered at [Which is grammatical correct? Woke to the ... or awoke to the ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132038/which-is-grammatical-correct-woke-to-the-or-awoke-to-the/132066#132066).

Comment: Much better, but 'come awake' not mentioned: [awoken vs awaked](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91114/awoken-vs-awaked/91117#91117)

Comment: Could you cite your source for the sentence you provide? It would help to know if the source is a recent one.

Comment: Oh, it was from the book and that is "The Sicilian" by Mario Puzo. As someone already said maybe it happens to appear more in literature?

Answer (score 1):

*Came awake* is not a normal way of saying it. The iWeb corpus has 85,784 instances of *woke up*, against 54 instances of *came awake*.

To me it suggests the suddenness of is - reinforced by the explicit *suddenly*. H didn't gradually wake up, he came awake.

Comment: I don't know about ***reinforced*** by the explicit "suddenly". There are [just as many hits in NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=slowly+came+awake%2Csuddenly+came+awake&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cslowly%20came%20awake%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuddenly%20came%20awake%3B%2Cc0) for ***slowly** came awake* as there are for ***suddenly** came awake*. To be "reinforced", it would have to already be the reader's "default", but in fact all it does is make the reader seek out some non-standard meaning for a non-standard usage.

Comment: Actually, I'm guessing that appending ***and*** to my search terms [***slowly / suddenly came to and***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=slowly+came+to+and%2Csuddenly+came+to+and&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cslowly%20came%20to%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuddenly%20came%20to%20and%3B%2Cc0) should largely restrict hits to those where ***come to** = awaken, regain consciousness*. And the NGram hits for *that* one strongly suggest we should associate ***come to*** with speed, but I'd never have thought that until now.

Comment: (But perhaps it is. The "slower" process might more often be referenced as ***come [a]round***.)

Comment: Maybe. Among the 54 _came awake_ in the iWeb corpus I count 7 where it is described as "sudden" (including "like a flash of lightning", "in a rush",  and "with a start"); and 2 where it is described as "slowly". There are also 9 instances of "with a gasp" (of some kind), or "with projectile vomiting". The rest are unmarked as to the speed (and some of them are figurative)

Comment: I think it's just the standard principle that whenever someone uses a noticeably less common, but nevertheless still "valid" turn of phrase, we assume it's intended tyo imply *some* difference from normal. In this case, ***come awake*** is rare compared to ***wake [up]***, so we "know" it's likely to reflect some semantic variation. And I guess the ***speed*** of the process (unusually fast ***or*** slow) is the most obvious candidate for some "variation from standard" nuance.